# Composite Foreign key in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I an trying to convert database schema into Database in ORACLE SQL

```
Books (BookID,PubID,Title,Author,Price,Availability)

Publisher (PubID,Name,Address,BookID)

Member (MemberID,Name,Address,MemberType,MemberDate,ExpiryDate)

Barrowings (MemberID,BookID,IssuedDate,ReturnDate,DueDate)
```

I have done first 3 tables. But i have a problem with the 4th table (Borrowings)
`(MemberID,BookID,IssueDate)` I want to make first 2 columns (MemberID,BookID) as a composite foreign key (Should refere 2 different tables)

MemberID referes the MemberID colimn in Member table
BookID referes the BookID table in Books table.
IssiedDate column is the primary key of that table
How to make a composite foreign key in ORACLE SQL

Comment: Please show your create statements for the tables so far.  FYI, no pl/sql needed for any of this.

Comment: "*IssuedDate is the primary key of that table*" - means that you can have exactly only one borrowing per day. You can't have two people borrow two different books on the same day then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create one foreign key referring to 2 parent tables.

In this case you need to create 2 foreign key constraints, one to BOOKS and other to MEMBER.

Answer (score 0):

Create table borrowings(
MemberID varchar2(20) constraint  fk_memid reference member(MemberID),
BookID varchar2(20) constraint  fk_bookid reference Books(BookID) )

For this purpose first you have to give primary key or Unique  on patent tables columns. I.e BookID column from books and memberid column from members..